# Replace with sed not working

Tags: bash, sed

```
#!/bin/bash
timezone=$(cat /etc/sysconfig/clock | sed 's/ZONE=//g')
sed -i "s/;date.timezone = .*/date.timezone = $timezone/g" /etc/php.ini
```

When i execute it i get

> sed: -e expression #1, char 48: unknown option to `s'

**Edit** Added output of command on my system**

```
cat /etc/sysconfig/clock | sed 's/ZONE=//g'
"America/Denver"
```

Final result should be

```
date.timezone = "America/Denver"
```

Comment: Maybe `$timezone` contains a slash?

Comment: BTW, don't use `cat` if not necessary. You can do simply `sed 's/ZONE=//g' /etc/sysconfig/clock`.

Answer (score 4):

your timezone variable contains '/'  use a different delimiter on your regex

eg: `@` is never used in timezones: and as @ChrisMaes says there may be other lines in that file which you do not want.

```
timezone=$(cat /etc/sysconfig/clock | grep ^ZONE= | sed 's/ZONE=//g')
# thanks Chris
timezone="${timezone//@/\\@}"
# thanks Phillip
sed -i "s@;date.timezone = .*@date.timezone = $timezone@g" /etc/php.ini
```

Comment: `@` is never used in timezones *right now*, but it is not explicitly forbidden, as far as I know. A safe and future-proof variant would be to add another substitution to the `sed` call that properly escapes any `@`.

Comment: @Phillip yeah, it's not particularly hard to escape the `@`s

Comment: nice and error-proof... although when escaping the `@` sign; you could as well keep using the `/` :)

Comment: @ChrisMaes perhaps, but how would I escape / in bash?  `${var//\//\\/}` looks more like a landscape than code

Comment: just saying :) It would work though. anyways your code is functional; I upvoted your answer already :)

Answer (score 2):

your `timezone` variable contains slashes and much more than you might want. Better add a line

```
echo "$timezone"
```

before your sed command to check its contents first...

the output of the command

```
cat /etc/sysconfig/clock | sed 's/ZONE=//g'
```

gives me the whole content of the /etc/sysconfig/clock file with just "ZONE=" removed. So your sed expression will be a huge mess since your variable `timezone` contains many lines with many slashes etc...

**edit** to fix your problem I recommend you to use @Jasen's answer: you can use `@` instead of `/` as a separator for sed.

Comment: I recommend you to use @Jasen's answer: you can use `@` instead of `/` as a separator for sed